# "Do you have planned" vs "Have you planned"

Tags: present-perfect, interrogatives

> So, what exactly do you have planned for your little jaunt up north?
> https://www.spanishdict.com/examples/jaunt?lang=en

I think the above sentence should be expressed as follows:

> So, what exactly **have you planned** for your little jaunt up north?

Is there something I don't understand well?

Comment: The first sentence seems a shortened version this sentence: "So, what exactly do you have, which is planned for your little jaunt up north?". You can simply omit "...which is...", that will result in the sentence you are asking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, but the function of the word "have" is very different.  In the second sentence "have" is an auxiliary verb and it forms the present perfect with the past participle.  In the first sentence, the verb "have" is the main verb and means "possess or own" (in some way)

It is easier if you convert the first sentence to a statement:

> I have a party planned for my trip.

This structure is "I have {Noun phase}".  The speaker possesses "a party" (in some figurative way) Saying "planned ..." is a past participle phrase, that describes the state of the party (it is still only a plan, etc)

Since "have" is a main verb, to form a question, do-support is needed, and the object pronoun is fronted, which leaves the participle at the end, immediately after "have".  This looks like the present perfect, but is not.

Answer (score 6):

"I have a trip planned" is the same sentence structure as "I have dinner ready".

Whereas "I have planned a trip" is a construction alike to "I have made dinner".

The meaning is similar, in the first pair of examples the focus is on the current state of things, while the second option gives more attention to the process of getting there.

You may also notice that in the first case, "planned" is in the role of an adjective, rather than part of the present perfect tense.